# Android server not available at http://localhost:8085/wd/hub

Tags: selenium, android-emulator

I am in the means of setting up of android web driver and followed the same steps as mentioned in the url : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

1) Downloaded the android SDK for windows and unpacked and placed in the path of selenium repository
 2) Set up the emulator and created the new AVD ( android virtual device ) 
3)Installed the webdriver apk 4)port forwarding in order to forward traffic from the host machine to the emulator.

In a terminal type:

```
$./adb -s forward tcp:8085 tcp:8085(since 8080 is occupied I'm using 8085)
```

5) This will make the android server available at `//localhost:8085/wd/hub` from my system.

But when i went to `localhost:8085/wd/hub` it displayed could not connect to `www.localhost.com:8085`. May I know why? Kindly help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "But when I went to" do you mean you visit the url in your browser? It sounds like your browser does not know what to do with the url and tries to be smart for you and assume you mean `www.localhost.com:8085`. If so, just add a protocol to your request. In stead of `localhost:8085/wd/hub` use `http://localhost:8085/wd/hub`.